# Regex : Using Regex in Java 8

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to manipulate a String, my String are :

```
 String string = "dfwx--05-dfpixc3"
```

I want my output to be like :

```
dfwx--05
dfpixc3
```

So the separator is `-` and not `--`

moreover, can I solve this problem using Matcher class Pattern class ?

Comment: Why not just use substring?

Comment: Because my String is variable
There always a number after --

Comment: You're using '`-`' as a field delimiter, and implicitly not allowing any of the fields themselves to start or end with '`-`'. That is, `dfwx--05` is always a single field and cannot represent two fields `dfwx` and `-05`. I hope this is just a practice/learning and not in use with real data. :-)

Comment: Just note, that the title should be significant, not a standard one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use split with this regex [`\b-\b`](https://regex101.com/r/7wibgi/1) with [Word Boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) like so :

> `\b` represents an anchor like caret (it is similar to `$` and `^`)
>   matching positions where one side is a word character (like `\w`) and
>   the other side is not a word character (for instance it may be the
>   beginning of the string or a space character).

```
String[] split = string.split("\\b-\\b");
```

---

> Because my String is variable There always a number after --

Another solution could be by using positive lookbehind, like so [`(?<=\d)-`](https://regex101.com/r/mpHrLJ/1) :

```
String[] split = string.split("(?<=\\d)-");
```

---

**Outputs**

```
[dfwx--05, dfpixc3]
```

Comment: `String str = "dfwx--05-dfpixc3";
        Arrays.stream(str.split("\\b-\\b")).forEach(System.out::println);` does the perfect job.

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of lookarounds:

```
(?<!-)-(?!-)
```

- `(?<!-)` - make sure the preceding char is not a dash
- `-` - make sure we are looking at a dash
- `(?!-)` - make sure the following char is not a dash

If I'm not mistaken, the code would be:

```
string.split("(?<!-)-(?!-)");
```

I don't know which online tester is best for Java but see https://regex101.com/r/LVXDdH/1 for a PCRE example.

---

Thank you [JGFMK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495157/jgfmk) for this Java specific test site:

https://repl.it/repls/ImpressionableBronzeMice

Comment: I would just do it like this. https://repl.it/repls/ImpressionableBronzeMice - Good point about additional dashes. I actually like your answer better personally than YCF_L's. Since it deals with the - character on it own. That in my eyes is cleaner/clearer.